# function not using updated variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I print currCalc2 it shows the correct string,
but when I use it with a previously defined function, it only inputs the first letter, not the full appended string.

I remember having this problem a long time ago, not sure how I fixed it. Been pulling my hair now for hours. Tried setting it to a global variable and been messing with syntax trying to get it to work.

```
def mapLocation(mapInput):

    #Final map location
    for i in mapInput:
        map_xy[0] = mapInput[1]-mapInput[0] #X Coordinate
        map_xy[1] = mapInput[2]-mapInput[3] #Y Coordinate
    return map_xy

def firstColission(calculateColission):

    visitedLocations=[]

    inputList = list(calculateColission)
    currLocation = (0,0)
    currCalc=[]
    for x in inputList:

        currCalc.append(x)
        currCalc2 = ''.join(currCalc)

        currLocation=mapLocation(mapInput(currCalc2))#mapInput(currCalc2))
        print(currLocation)

        visitedLocations.append(currLocation)
```

I expect an output of: `[0, 1] [1, 1] [0, 2]` etc. But I get `[0, 1] [0, 1] [0, 1]`

Comment: I expect an output of:
[0, 1]
[1, 1]
[0, 2]
etc.

But I get
[0, 1]
[0, 1]
[0, 1]

Comment: I wanted to make it part of the question at first, but it kept giving me an error thinking it should be part of the code, didn't let me post before I took that part out. Hence why I posted it afterwards

Comment: Did you provide enough information for someone to help? What are `mapInput`, `mapLocation`? How about a minimal example of `calculateColission`.  Please read [mcve]

Comment: I think I added enough information to help as it's not a question about those functions, rather why I can't seem to use my existing functions and variables as input for said function, as it does not update.

Comment: There is something funny going on in `beenHere`. ... `seen = visitedLocations=[]; for currLocation in visitedLocations:` `visitedLocations` is always empty at the *top-of-the-loop* so nothing happens, it just falls through to `return False`.

Comment: Managed to debug further, using what you told me. I removed beenHere completely. I now know the problem is with mapLocation(), it sticks to the first value it gets and doesn't update after that. This is the mapLocation() function:

Added MapLocation() to the top of original post

Comment: Still not enough information.  You should be able to write tests for your functions and validate that they work - that's one of the good things about functions.  If you KNOW a function works and it is giving you the wrong result, then you must be giving it the wrong data.  [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: [Testing and Debugging](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-00-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-fall-2008/video-lectures/lecture-11/) lecture.